# Uncaught ReferenceError: __importDefault is not defined; After going to Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

After running

```
ng serve
```

In the browser, developer tools, I see the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __importDefault is not defined
    at Module../src/app/home/home.component.ts (home.component.ts:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app-routing.module.ts (main.js:98)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/main.ts (environment.ts:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

In my home.component.ts I have the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'miles-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is my settings:

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.3
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.0.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms     
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------     
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.25
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.25
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.3
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      9.0.3
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.25
@schematics/angular               9.0.3
@schematics/update                0.900.3
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Line 5 is simply the templateURL so not sure what it's complaining about...

Comment: Can it not find the template for some reason? Did you go from the latest v8.x > 9 or did you jump a version?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32215

Comment: I've added my environment settings from ng version command. I read the link but didn't find any solution that helped @NadeemShaikh

Comment: @mwilson I did it step by step following this guide https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0

Comment: I would read through the github issue added by @NadeemShaikh. It's more than likely your issue. Which version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: it might be because of `@angular-devkit/architect` is still pointiing to the angular 8 not anngular 9?

Comment: @AniruddhaDas I dug a bit deeper about the devkit and put an answer to what ultimately got it to work. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up running this in the terminal, here's the magic:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest
```

Comment: @AniruddhaDas indeed!

Comment: If anyone comes across this same issue in the future but is using yarn instead of npm you would install do yarn add  @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest -d